# Add button to the top toolbar on Case screen

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add a new toolbar button next to "TAKE CASE" in Case screen (CR306000). I have customize CRCaseMaint DAC but still the button is not appearing. Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: Can you share the code you added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replicated this and issue and solution was PXAction should be public.  In sample above its marked as private.

code as follows works:

```
public class CaseExtension : PXGraphExtension<CRCaseMaint>
{
    public PXAction<CRCase> Change2;

    [PXButton(CommitChanges=true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Change Me")]
    protected virtual void change2()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following steps are needed for you: 
1. Create class library (CL).
2. Reference in created CL dlls from Acumatica folder which start from PX.*
3. In CL add new class CRCaseMaintExt with member TakeCase like this:

```
public class CRCaseMaintExt : PXGraphExtension<CRCaseMaint>
{
        private PXAction<CRCase> TakeCase2;

        [PXButton]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Take Case")]
        public virtual IEnumerable takeCase2(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            //your custom code
            return adapter.Get();
        }
}
```

4. Take note, that case in TakeCase and takeCase matter. Also matters PXAction
5. Build CL
6. Add reference to CL to your Acumatica project.

Comment: The type 'PX.Objects.CR.CRCaseMaint' cannot be used as type parameter 'Table' in the generic type or method 'PX.Data.PXCacheExtension<Table>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'PX.Objects.CR.CRCaseMaint' to 'PX.Data.IBqlTable'.

Comment: Oh, sorry, please replace PXCacheExtension with PXGraphExtension. I modified in answer also

Comment: Still the button is not appearing. Surprisingly there is no error, it simply executes the above code but button is not appearing.

Comment: are you sure that you referenced class library ?

Comment: Yes, I have referenced PX.Common, PX.Data, PX.Objects in my CL. And added reference of my CL into Acumatica website. Actually my CL reference DLL is already added into Acumatica website bin folder as I have created an Addon Project from Acumatica.

Comment: Please see me another answer. Acumatica team has already implemented this button. I propose you to figure out what is edition of acumatica team in order to avoid two buttons simultaneously to appear at screen

Comment: I've displayed how to add another button, but there are chances that you'll get two buttons "Take Case"

Comment: Unfortunately not Yura. I am surprise I have done exactly what you have mentioned here, but button is not at all appearing on the screen. There is one more code which I need to place in CR306000.aspx page for CallbackCommand for datasource. But nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another reason. In base graph there is code

```
public PXAction<CRCase> takeCase;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Take Case", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
        [PXButton]
        public virtual IEnumerable TakeCase(PXAdapter adapter)
```

Acumatica itself has button TakeCase which blocks your button TakeCase. You need to understand, why you need another one button Take Case because Acumatica team already implemented it. Are you sure you want to replace it?

Comment: No I do not want to replace the existing button. I want to create one new button "CreateCase" through which I want to submit a case to another site.

Comment: Then you can use TakeCase2, which is in modified first answer